# openvpn tun forwarding with firewalld

Tags: openvpn, firewalld

I have an OpenVPN server on Fedora 19 with 2 clients - 1 client on the same LAN as the server, and the other on the internet.
I want the 2 clients to be able to talk to each other thru the tunnel and, if I stop firewalld.service on the server, they can.
How can I configure firewalld to allow this traffic? either with the GUI, or with firewall-cmd.
I think the equivalent iptables commands would be:

> iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
>   iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT

How to do that with firewalld?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, but this finally worked for me:

- First, enable forwarding:

  `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
- And then authorize your `tun0` interface with firewalld:

  `firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=tun0`

Add `--permanent` to the last command to make it persistant.

I had nothing more to do except the usual OpenVPN configuration.

Comment: You just inspired me to completely isolate all clients by firewall-cmd --zone=block --add-interface=tun0 Thanks.

Comment: When you say "the usual OpenVPN configuration", what other "usual" firewall-cmd's would apply (assuming OpenVPN is running on TCP 443), and to which zones?

Comment: infinity upvoats for you